# What is a good regular expression tester for OS X?

Tags: regex, macos, user-interface

I'm looking for a GUI based RegExp tester in the vein of [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/), or this [JavaScript expression tester](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/) here, for OS X, to help me when writing regular expressions.

It would be really handy for it to work in more than one language (i.e. Python, JavaScript, or Ruby).

Other than using MacVim's own find as you type tool, or a command line editor like Vim or Emacs, (I use Textmate as my main editor), what are my options here?

Comment: Try https://codverter.com/src/regextester

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [reggyapp.com](http://reggyapp.com/images/screenshots/1.3/main.png))</sub>

give [Reggy](http://reggyapp.com/screenshots/#1.3) a try! ...simple and effective!

**NOTE:** Though the last 1.3 release of the app is quite old (2007), a new version written in Objective-c is under development on [Github](http://github.com/samsouder/reggy/tree/master)

Comment: Unfortunately no longer compatible with macOS Catalina due to 64bits application requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just use one of the online RegExp testers, like "[RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)".

Comment: This is actually one of my favourites but it does not support lookahead and lookbehind as it is written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nice Regexp tester for JavaScript at http://robrohan.com/projects/widgets/, which is available as a widget for OS X, and is even nice enough to give you numbered captures, something that's quite rare amongst RegExp testers.

However, to buy it you need to send some unspecified amount of money via paypal for it - I flipped a dollar in, partly because I didn't know whether it would be any good, and it turns out to be pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite WebApp to test for regular expressions is **[RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/)**.

But this was not the question ;)

So, if you really need an app, take a look at **[RegExhibit](http://roger-jolly.nl/software/#regexhibit)** from Roger Jolly. It's quite simple and gives you the ability to **find**, **replace** and **split**.

By the way, RegExhibit is free an open-source!

Answer (score 0):

I've used and liked JRegExpTester:

http://jregexptester.sourceforge.net/

It's in Java and only does Java regexes, unfortunately.

There's also a handy FF plugin:

http://sebastianzartner.de/firefoxExtensions/RExT/

Answer (score 0):

*I realize this question is quite old, but...*

I prefer to download/buy from the App Store. So I spent the $2.99 and gave [**Patterns**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/patterns-the-regex-app/id429449079?mt=12) a try. There are a few other good looking RegEx GUI applications on the App Store, but all of them are double the price and offer little to no extra functionality.

Comment: Oyster is a strong contender lets you keep a library. Dash and Codebox integration too. http://www.rwe-uk.com/app/oyster

Answer (score -1):

You should check out [iRegEx](http://www.fireblink.com/fireapps/iregex). It's the fastest, leanest, and it has the best UI. And it's the cheapest too. It only needs a decent icon… ;)